# kate saving a text file that needs sudo, opens a password dialog message

Tags: sudo, password, kate

I use to have a setup that i could edit and save a file using (Kate text editor) that needed sudo privilage. On save it will show a dialog asking me for my password. 
This was really handy. But it is not working anymore. Now i get an error that the document could not be saved.

The goal for me is that i can double click on any text file that opens with Kate. And when i save it, it will prompt a password dialog when needed.

Does anybody has an idea how to get the dialog back that is asking for my password?

I'm using Kubuntu 16.04.
My Kate version is: 16.04.3

[image]

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.                                                                                                       
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```

This happend when i was trying to save .bashrc in my home folder.

```
drwxr-xr-x  137 billy billy     36864 Oct 16 13:43 .
drwxr-xr-x    5 root  root       4096 Feb 17  2018 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 root  root       9907 Sep 24 21:28 .bashrc
```

But it seems to happen with all files that i need sudo for.

Kind regards,
Billy

Comment: When i do:
`~$ kate -v`

Comment: output: kate 16.04.3

Comment: I thought that is would be the version that i'm running at the moment?

Comment: Where did you obtain it? The version I find in the repositories for 16.04 is `kate 15.12.3`

Comment: Just thru updates: sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y && sudo apt dist-upgrade -y && sudo apt autoremove -y && sudo apt autoclean -y

Comment: I have added a screenshot of the version numbers from the system info.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include the output of `lsb_release -a`

Comment: It appears that you obtained kate through [Kubuntu backports.](https://pkgs.org/download/kate)  Please [edit] your post to include the output of `ls -l directoryname` where directoryname is the directory mentioned in the error you get when you can't save the file. Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: The file i want to save in .bashrc in my home folder. I added that in the post.
But it seems to work the same for all other files where i need sudo for.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84557/discussion-between-elder-geek-and-billy).

Comment: @ElderGeek here's a bit of background re. this subject: https://blog.martin-graesslin.com/blog/2017/02/editing-files-as-root/

Answer (score 1):

You haven't mentioned your distro! I'm assuming you're on Kubuntu 18.04 which has `Kate Version 17.12.3`.

Open a terminal, move to the folder containing the file you want to edit. In this example, I want to edit the `gtkrc` file located in `/usr/share/themes/Crux/gtk-2.0/`.

So, first

`cd /usr/share/themes/Crux/gtk-2.0/`

Then run `SUDO_EDITOR=kate sudoedit gtkrc` exactly as typed including the `_` between `SUDO` and `EDITOR`.

`/usr/share/themes/Crux/gtk-2.0 $ SUDO_EDITOR=kate sudoedit gtkrc`

On pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>, provide your password and press  <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Kate will open the file. Make your edits and save as usual. Done.

When Plasma 5.13 arrives, you'll be able to open any suitable file with Kate and edit it. When you attempt to save it, you'll be prompted to provide your password if you've edited a system file.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm using Kubuntu 16.04. I have also added the distro to the question. 
I don't have the Crux theme. I use Breeze-dark.

Comment: I have tried this in the Default theme folder and in the Breeze-dark folder.  But i don't seem to get this working i think.

Comment: Well, I don't know what else to suggest because you aren't explaining what you mean by "i don't seem to get this working". Do you mean the editing and saving didn't work **or** that the edit you made didn't have the desired visual result? The `Crux` theme was an example :)

Comment: Sorry, when i run "SUDO_EDITOR=kate sudoedit gtkrc" in that folder. Enter my password, Kate opens, that file. I am able to save this file. But i don't understand what i should add or change in this file. 

I tried to add "SUDO_EDITOR=kate sudoedit gtkrc" in that file. But to be Frank, i don't know what i'm doing. Or it that even should be there.

The goal for me is that i can double click on any text file that opens with Kate. And when i save it, it will prompt a password dialog when needed.

Comment: "The goal for me is that i can double click on any text file that opens with Kate. And when i save it, it will prompt a password dialog when needed." That's not possible with the version of Kate you have.

Comment: Strange, i had exactly that working for a very long time. But i did a big cleanup of alot of packages last weekend. And it stopt working.

Comment: But if i want it again i may have to wait for "Plasma 5.13"?